# Pandas - Bar chart with grouped-data, with the order of groups being sorted by data from another list

Tags: sorting, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

### Requirements:

- I'm trying to create a bar graph where, for each condition ("label"), I show the mean task time for each manipulation ("pattern"). So, there will be 8 groups of 3 bars, and one group with a single bar.
- I need to show error bars (standard error) on each of these bars.
- **I want the order of each condition/label to be determined from some calculations done using some other metrics. (These I've already extracted into a dict mapping from label ==> index/order)**
- I'm going to be drawing a few other graphs, and whatever sort order is used in this must be the same across the others too
- This is with Python 2.7, Pandas 0.18, and in an IPython Notebook
- (The dataframe is loaded from a csv file, and not constructed directly)

### Problem:

So, here is what the graph currently looks like:

[Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avLyr.png)

I've replaced/removed the labels for uploading here, but, just like these labels, the originals were sorted alphabetically.

And therein lies the problem: **I *don't* want each technique sorted alphabetically. Instead, I want them to be sorted based on a sorting order I've got in a separate list** (i.e. so that I can get them showing up in a sequential order - shortest to tallest, while maintaining the same order across graphs).

### Current Code:

So, I load the full dataset in from a csv file:

```
p = pd.read_csv("...", sep='\t')
```

Then, I use groupby to extract the "task_time" data to draw each bar:

```
tt_all = p.groupby(['label', 'pattern'])[['task_time']]
```

This is then drawn by doing:

```
tt_all.mean().unstack().plot(kind='bar', yerr=tt_all.sem().unstack(), figsize=(15, 6), cmap=cmap, edgecolor='None', rot=45)
```

(Without unstack(), it just shoves everything into a single category and creates a mess)

### What I've tried:

After a lot of poking around, I've managed to get the following:

```
# Create a column to use for sorting things
sort_order_keys = {'I': 8, 'F': 3, 'H': 7, 'G': 1, 'D': 2, 'C': 5, 'E': 6, 'A': 4, 'B': 0}
p['label_sort_key'] = p['label'].apply(lambda x: sort_order_keys[x])  

# This sorts all the rows by the sort order
tt_all_raw = p.sort(['label_sort_key', 'pattern'])
tt_all_raw = tt_all_raw.iloc[tt_all_raw['label_sort_key'].argsort()]
print tt_all_raw     # <--- This will be sorted correctly

# Performing grouping....
tt_all = tt_all_raw.groupby(['label', 'pattern'], sort=False)[['task_time']]
print tt_all.mean()   # <---- This will also be sorted correctly

print tt_all.mean().unstack()  # <--- This however forces everything back to alphabetical order! Argh!
```

### Question(s)

- How can I re-sort the unstack() results?   OR
- Is there an easier way to set up a graph like this, with these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical-index) with categories with custom order, which is easy sorted by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
print (p)
  label  pattern  task_time
0     I        0          3
1     E        0          0
2     B        1          2
3     D        1          1
4     G        1          0
5     F        0          3
6     H        0          0
7     D        1          2
8     A        1          1
9     C        1          0
```

```
tt_all = p.groupby(['label', 'pattern'])[['task_time']]
print (tt_all.mean())
               task_time
label pattern           
A     1              1.0
B     1              2.0
C     1              0.0
D     1              1.5
E     0              0.0
F     0              3.0
G     1              0.0
H     0              0.0
I     0              3.0

df1 = tt_all.mean().unstack()
df1.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df1.index, 
                                categories=['B', 'G', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'H', 'I'], 
                                ordered=True)
df1.sort_index(inplace=True)
print (df1)
        task_time     
pattern         0    1
B             NaN  2.0
G             NaN  0.0
D             NaN  1.5
F             3.0  NaN
A             NaN  1.0
C             NaN  0.0
E             0.0  NaN
H             0.0  NaN
I             3.0  NaN
```

Comment: This works, but now the order of bars within each group (i.e. "pattern") gets changed too (I'd like it to stay the way it is now)

Comment: Here's part of the dataset:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6MoRLgRcIqabHh5OTdjck1vbWc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I bypassed this by mutating the `GroupBy object` into a `DataFrame` and passing the orderd categories as a list to the `index` parameter.

Would this work for you?

```
sort_order_keys = ['B', 'G', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'H', 'I']
tt_all = pandas.DataFrame(tt_all, index = sort_order_keys)
```

You should then be able to use the plotting functions on the dataframe.

When using the `.count()` method on the group, I found that it is useful to transform the `GroupBy object` into a dictionary using `dict()` before passing it to the `pandas.DataFrame()` function and use the group labels as labels for the columns and naming the `index` as 'count', for example:

```
tt_allCount = pandas.DataFrame(dict(tt_all.count()), 
                                    columns = sort_order_keys,
                                    index=['count'])
```